# Return ActionResult as 301

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I want to return a `RedirectResult` for an action, but without the `Url.Action()`. Let's say I have the following `Controller`.

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var url = Url.Action("CustomerAndProduct", new { customerId = 1, orderId = 2, productId = 3} );
        return Redirect(url);
    }

    public ActionResult CustomerAndProduct(int customerId, int orderId, int productId)
    {
        // I want to get here...
    }
}
```

**Is there any way I can return a `RedirectResult` without manually specifying both the action name and all the parameters by using strings?** The reason is that I find it cumbersome to maintain these strings if the action name or a parameter name change. Then it's not detected on compile.

Perhaps like so:

```
var url = Url.FromAction<CustomerController>(x => x.CustomerAndProduct(1, 2, 3));
return Result(url);
```

Very much like one can do with the [Futures library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Futures/):

```
Html.BeginForm<CustomerController>(x => x.CustomerAndProduct(1, 2, 3))
```

Note that I don't want to execute the `CustomerAndProduct`. I just want to return the url as a `301` or `302`.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are asking for some kind of type safety? If so have a look at t4MVC https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC It will let you write

```
return RedirectToAction(MVC.Customer.CustomerAndProduct(1,2,3));
```

Comment: Welcome to the 100+ club. ;) Good example. However, I try to keep 3rd parties down to a minimum and am already using Futures, which provides the same thing for most of the helpers.